# can the font family and size be altered for a createmenu statement?

Tags: google-apps-script, menu, menuitem

The menu options I am presenting have gotten too long for the screen. I would like to reduce the font size in order to fit more items on the screen. I know I can break this into into sub-menus if there is no other alternative.

I have researched and found no options on the `createmenu` statement that can control this. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Please provide [mcve].  In general we don't have the ability to modify the Google UI

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are asking to do cannot be done, because Google Docs Editors such as Google Sheets, Google Slides and Google Docs do not support customization of built-in user interface elements.

To make a large number of menu items more manageable, use [Menu.addSubMenu()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addsubmenumenu) to create a hierarchy of menu items.